# unordered_map vs vector + custom hashing for small number of elements

Tags: c++, vector, hashmap, unordered-map

Current I have a nested hashmap. The inner map key has a very large range but the outer map key has only 10 different possible strings.

```
unordered_map<string, unordered_map<int, list<string>>> nestedHashMap;
```

Would it be more efficient for me to switch to

```
vector<unordered_map<int, list<string>>>
```

and have my own hashfunction

```
static int hashFunc(string stringToBeHashed){
        switch(stringToBeHashed){
            case "example1":
                return 0;
            .
            .
            .
            case "example10":
                return 9;
            default:
                return -1;
        }
    }
```

and do my own hashing before every look up? In terms of space complexity, due to the fact that the unordered_map is a node based container, I think this vector approach would save me some per-node memory required by unordered_map. Also, I am assuming the inner hashmap would guarantee fastest retrieval even though the key is an int. The key has a large range so I don't think using a vector here would increase performance. Right? Any comments/tips would be appreciated.

Memory is not an issue here.

Comment: Try various variations and measure their performance. Then come back and tell everyone else so we can all learn.

Comment: While you are at it, consider `vector<string>` in place of `list<string>`. The results may shock and dismay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone was wondering, did a quick code profiling with

```
vector<unordered_map<int, list<string>>
map<string, unordered_map<int, list<string>>
unordered_map<string, vector<unordered_map<int, list<string>>
```

vector had the fastest average time followed by unordered_map followed by map.

Comment: This answer would be dramatically much more useful and helpful if it said whether the difference is 2% or 2000%.

Answer (score 2):

> The inner map key has a very large range

That's exactly why hashmap is a right choice here

> but the outer map key has only 10 different possible strings

And there you're misusing the hashmap. 
Replace it with a tree(`std::map`) instead.
(Yes, you can choose `std::vector` if you want to write a lookup function youself)
BTW, you should not be concerned with space complexity topic when you have only 10 elements :)
**Update:**
Your outer container's purpose is basically to store 10 elements.
It is a tiny number so in theory you can chose whatever
cotainer you want (array, tree, hashtable).
So you should choose the best fit.
Choices are:

- `std::map`: least code to write, sorts elements automatically
- `std::vector`: best use of space, but you should write a lookup function youself
- `std::hashmap`: shooting out of cannon into sparrows. You don't need 99% of functionality it provides. This contaner has different purpose than yours

Comment: 10 elements as in 10 possible elements for the outer hashmap. I'm dealing with millions of data that's hashed into the 10 different locations and then the inner hashmap is where things get pretty big. But why would I prefer a map over unordered_map in the case of 10 possible mappings?

Comment: makes sense. Thanks!